# Best database for my type of application? MySQL? MongoDB? PostgreSQL? CouchDB?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, postgresql, redis

I am currently writing an application where i have to store a huge amount of data. My application is written in Node.js and im using the cluster and async module to make use of my complete system.

Here are some properties of my application and the environment i am using:

**Workstation:**

- CPU: 6 Cores at 3.5 GHz
- RAM: 16 GB
- Nodejs: latest version
- Current Database: MySQL
- OS: Windows 10

**Application:**

- Is using currently 6 workers each taking 0.1% CPU and 80 MB of RAM
- Gets Data for the Database via RPC calls in JSON format

**Data:**

- Blocks (currently ~376,000 Blocks) increasing every ~10min by one. Example Data for one Block:

  ```js
  {
      "hash" : "000000000fe549a89848c76070d4132872cfb6efe5315d01d7ef77e4900f2d39",
      "confirmations" : 88029,
      "size" : 189,
      "height" : 227252,
      "version" : 2,
      "merkleroot" : "c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a",
      "tx" : [
          "c738fb8e22750b6d3511ed0049a96558b0bc57046f3f77771ec825b22d6a6f4a"
      ],
      "time" : 1398824312,
      "nonce" : 1883462912,
      "bits" : "1d00ffff",
      "difficulty" : 1.00000000,
      "chainwork" : "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000083ada4a4009841a",
      "previousblockhash" : "00000000c7f4990e6ebf71ad7e21a47131dfeb22c759505b3998d7a814c011df",
      "nextblockhash" : "00000000afe1928529ac766f1237657819a11cfcc8ca6d67f119e868ed5b6188"
  }
  ```

  - Transactions (currently ~84,850,717 Transactions) increasing every second by ~1.3 Transactions. Example Data for one transaction:

```js
{
    "hex" : "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",
    "txid" : "ef7c0cbf6ba5af68d2ea239bba709b26ff7b0b669839a63bb01c2cb8e8de481e",
    "version" : 1,
    "locktime" : 0,
    "vin" : [
        {
            "txid" : "d7c7557e5ca87d439e9ab6eb69a04a9664a0738ff20f6f083c1db2bfd79a8a26",
            "vout" : 0,
            "scriptSig" : {
                "asm" : "3045022100ee69171016b7dd218491faf6e13f53d40d64f4b40123a2de52560feb95de63b902206f23a0919471eaa1e45a0982ed288d374397d30dff541b2dd45a4c3d0041acc001 03a7c1fd1fdec50e1cf3f0cc8cb4378cd8e9a2cee8ca9b3118f3db16cbbcf8f326",
                "hex" : "483045022100ee69171016b7dd218491faf6e13f53d40d64f4b40123a2de52560feb95de63b902206f23a0919471eaa1e45a0982ed288d374397d30dff541b2dd45a4c3d0041acc0012103a7c1fd1fdec50e1cf3f0cc8cb4378cd8e9a2cee8ca9b3118f3db16cbbcf8f326"
            },
            "sequence" : 4294967295
        }
    ],
    "vout" : [
        {
            "value" : 0.39890000,
            "n" : 0,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 56847befbd2360df0e35b4e3b77bae48585ae068 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex" : "76a91456847befbd2360df0e35b4e3b77bae48585ae06888ac",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "moQR7i8XM4rSGoNwEsw3h4YEuduuP6mxw7"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "value" : 0.10000000,
            "n" : 1,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 2b14950b8d31620c6cc923c5408a701b1ec0a020 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex" : "76a9142b14950b8d31620c6cc923c5408a701b1ec0a02088ac",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "mjSk1Ny9spzU2fouzYgLqGUD8U41iR35QN"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "value" : 0.20000000,
            "n" : 2,
            "scriptPubKey" : {
                "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 0dfc8bafc8419853b34d5e072ad37d1a5159f584 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex" : "76a9140dfc8bafc8419853b34d5e072ad37d1a5159f58488ac",
                "reqSigs" : 1,
                "type" : "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses" : [
                    "mgnucj8nYqdrPFh2JfZSB1NmUThUGnmsqe"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "blockhash" : "00000000103e0091b7d27e5dc744a305108f0c752be249893c749e19c1c82317",
    "confirmations" : 88192,
    "time" : 1398734825,
    "blocktime" : 1398734825
}
```

**Problem:**
The MySQL Database is pushing the CPU to 100% while using only 500MB of RAM. My bottleneck is currently the MySQL Database which is not able to handle the speed and the amount of data from my application and is taking a lot of CPU power.

**What i am looking for:**

- A database which can handle my application even when i am increasing the worker amount

  - It should be easy to retrieve the information and to select data which has dependencies. (Blocks have a connection to transactions through the tx <--> txid value)
  - Should be able to hold even more data in the future because of the steady increase of data
  - Needs to be accessable by multiple workers at the same time
  - Bonus: Sort of notification (channel) to my application when data is changing

I hope someone can give me a suggestion which database is suitable for my type of project and give me maybe a  guess on the needed storage amount.

You can suggest me also another database which i haven't mentioned in the title.

Comment: Because it looks like your data will be mostly immutable after it has been written, and because there is a clear index and you probably do not need to do very complicated queries on it, I think a document store would work well for your situation, and a relational database like MySQL or PostgreSQL would likely be overkill. Out of your listed options, MongoDB and Redis fit the document-store requirement, but Redis is inappropriate because it likes to keep data in RAM, which you’re low on. There are other solutions which could be appropriate too; in any case, I think you want a **document store**

Comment: An example of another document store not in your list could be [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/). In any case, I’m not terribly familiar with the pros and cons of each, but that’s a starting point.

Comment: @icktoofay You could be right. Well im not sure what counts as complicated queries. Is MongoDB CPU intensive and what do you guess how much storage it would take?

Comment: If you want to query for records by a particular field (e.g. find the transaction by this hash, or find all transactions in this timestamp range), you’re going to have no problem whatsoever. If you wanted to find, say, all transactions whose 100th ancestor has a hash that ends with `abcd`, that probably won’t work very well. I don’t have much experience with administrating MongoDB, so I can’t say much about its CPU usage or storage space. I imagine neither are too unreasonable but I would recommend trying it in a test environment to see if you think it would work for you.

Comment: @icktoofay Ok thanks for your help i am going to try mongodb. I hope i can atleast query all transactions which belong to one block. When this test is failing i may try PostgreSQL

Comment: Yeah, if you have a block ID, you’ll have no problem querying for all transactions in that block. Create an index on the block ID for the transactions collection, and it’ll be able to handle that kind of query easily.

Comment: PostgreSQL is way better at handling heavy-usage scenarios for relational databases than MySQL ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relational databases are useful when you have, well, lots of relations between things, and particularly when you’ll want to traverse through those relations while querying. For example, you could have a bunch of customers, each having a number of orders, which are all from suppliers, which are in locations; you might want to query for all customers who have at least five orders from suppliers in a particular location. Or maybe you want to know the total number of orders from suppliers, grouped by location. Relational databases are excellent at this.

Your data does have relations, yes. However, it sounds like you aren’t planning on trying to traverse through them or aggregate them very much, and your data, once stored, will seldom if ever change. That sounds to me like a document store would better suit you.

Out of the databases you list, MongoDB and Redis could be considered document stores. You said you had only 512 MB of RAM; that kind of disqualifies Redis, which loves to store *all* of its data in RAM, with throwing it onto disk as an afterthought. I’m not sure what balance MongoDB tries to strike, but I believe that while it uses RAM somewhat liberally, it also does try to get it to disk, eventually. (Some people poke fun at it, saying that it doesn’t try very hard at durability. It looks like you’re storing data that’s publicly available, so that shouldn’t be too much of a problem—if you lose some most-recently-written data, you can just repopulate it from a public source.)

In the comments, you pointed out that you were very commonly going to be querying for all transactions in a block. MongoDB should be able to deal with that use-case with ease. The only thing you’ll need to make sure of is that you create an index on the block-ID column (field? I’m not sure what MongoDB calls them), which should allow for that kind of query to be efficiently executed.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. One point wasn't correct. I said mysql only is using 500 MB of ram not that i have only 500MB. I have 16GB of ram so i think redis is also an option.